# how to execute process management commands in linux by using switch case in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have created gui using zenity and displayed some of the process management commands. Now i want to use switchcase and execute them. 
coomands like create,kill etc

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple script which starts some processes in the background and then supplies a `read` based interface for the user to select which process to kill. It could perhaps be expanded by using an array of PIDs with a more powerful shell

```
#!/bin/sh


yes > logfile.txt & PID1="$!"

yes > logfile.txt & PID2="$!"

while ! [ $PID1 -eq 0 -a $PID2 -eq 0 ]
do clear
   printf "Type the process number you wish to kill or q to quit\n"
   printf "The Processes we are tracking are:\n"

   [ $PID1 -gt 0 ] && printf "PID %s\n" "$PID1"
   [ $PID2 -gt 0 ] && printf "PID %s\n" "$PID2"

   read i

   case "$i" in
       "$PID1" ) kill "$PID1"
                 PID1=0
                 ;;
       "$PID2" ) kill "$PID2"
                 PID2=0
                 ;;
              q) kill "$PID1" "$PID2"
                 ;;
   esac
done
```